# Overloading Operators with MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, class, operator-overloading

I'm currently writing a code to perform Gaussian elimination in MATLAB and then write out the code needed to generate a LaTex file showing all the steps. A lot of the times when I do Gaussian elimination the answers start turning into Fractions. So I thought as a nice learning exercise for classes in Matlab that I would write a Fraction class. But I have no clue how to overload operators and frankly Mathwork's documentation wasn't helpful.

```
classdef Fraction

properties
    numer
    denom
end

methods
    function a = Fraction(numer,denom)
       a.denom = denom;
       a.numer = numer;
    end

    function r = mtimes(a,b)
        r = Fraction(a.numer*b.numer,a.denom*b.demon);
    end

    function r = plus(a,b)
        c = a.numer*b.denom+a.denom*b.numer;
        d = a.denom*b.denom;
        r = Fraction(c,d);

    function r = minus(a,b)
        c = a.numer*b.denom-a.denom*b.numer;
        d = a.denom*b.denom;
        r = Fraction(c,d);
    end

    function r = mrdivide(a,b)
        r = Fraction(a.numer*b.denom,a.denom*b.numer);
    end

    function b = reduceFrac(a)
    x = a.numer;
    y = b.denom;
    while y ~= 0
        x = y;
        y = mod(x,y);
    end
    b =Fraction(a.numer/x, a.denom/x)

    end
end

end
```

The plus operator works but the other three do not. Does any one have any ideas? Also how do I call my method reduceFrac?

```
Fraction.reduceFrac(Fraction(2.4))
```

I thought that the code above would work, but it didn't. Below is the python version of what I am trying to acheive.

## Fraction.py

```
class Fraction(object):
"""Fraction class


Attributes:
    numer: the numerator of the fraction.

    denom: the denominator of the fraction.
"""

def __init__(self, numer, denom):
     """Initializes the Fraction class

     Sets the inital numer and denom for the
     fraction class.

Args:
    numer: Top number of the Fraction

    denom: Bottom number of the Fraction

Returns:
    None

Raises:
    None
    """
    self.numer = numer
    self.denom = denom

def __str__(self):
    """function call along with the print command

Args:
    None

Returns:
    String: numer / denom. 

Raises:
    None
    """
    return str(self.numer) + '/' + str(self.denom)

def get_numer(self):
    return self.numer

def set_numer(self, numer):
    self.numer = numer

def get_denom(self):
    return self.denom

def set_denom(self, denom):
    self.denom = denom

def __add__(self, other):
    numer = self.numer*other.denom+other.numer*self.denom
    denom = self.denom*other.denom
    return Fraction.reduceFrac(Fraction(numer,denom))

def __div__(self, other):
    numer = self.numer*other.denom
    denom = self.denom*other.numer
    return Fraction.reduceFrac(Fraction(numer,denom))

def __sub__(self, other):
    numer = self.numer*other.denom-other.numer*self.denom
    denom = self.denom*other.denom
    return Fraction.reduceFrac(Fraction(numer,denom))

def __mul__(self, other):
    numer = self.numer*other.numer
    denom = self.denom*other.denom
    return Fraction.reduceFrac(Fraction(numer,denom))

def reduceFrac(self):
    x = self.numer
    y = self.denom
    while y != 0:
        (x, y) = (y, x % y)
    return Fraction(self.numer/x, self.denom/x)


if __name__ == "__main__":
v = Fraction(4,3)
g = Fraction(7,8)
r = Fraction(4,8)

a = v + g
print a

s = v - g
print s

d = v / g
print d

m = v * g
print m

f = Fraction.reduceFrac(r)
print f
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about how they are not working? Are you getting error messages when you attempt to use the overloaded operators? Or unexpected results? How are you invoking the overloaded operations?

Comment: In your Matlab code, `reduceFrac` is a regular object method, so you can call it on a Fraction `x` with `x.reduceFrac()` or the alternate old-style syntax `reduceFrac(x)`. However, its second line is `y = b.denom;` which is referencing the output and should throw an error; that probabbly should be `y = a.denom;`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `plus` function misses an `end`

Comment: That was just a mistake from my copying and pasting poorly. I always have trouble posting code on stackoverflow

Comment: After setting the end, your code runs fine. Maybe you need a clear all to get the updated class active?